# Algorithm finding minimum bounding rectangle for given circles not evaluating correctly

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to find the smallest bounding rectangle of a number of circles given the x and y co-ordinates of their centre and the magnitude of the radii.

The test input is:

```
(1, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0.5), (-1, -3, 2), (5, 2, 1)
```

Here's my code:

```
package com.CocoMac.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Challenge330Easy {
    static double maxx;
    static double maxy;
    static double minx;
    static double miny;

    static ArrayList <double[]> circles = new ArrayList<double[]>();

    static String in = "1,1,2\n2,2,0.5\n-1,-3,2\n5,2,1";
    static String s;

    static Scanner inScan = new Scanner(in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; inScan.hasNextLine(); i++) {
            s = inScan.nextLine();
            circles.add(i, toDouble(s.split(",")));

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
                if(maxx < circles.get(i)[0] + circles.get(i)[2]);
                    maxx = circles.get(i)[0] + circles.get(i)[2];

                if(minx > circles.get(i)[0] - circles.get(i)[2]);
                    minx = circles.get(i)[0] - circles.get(i)[2];

                if(maxy < circles.get(i)[1] + circles.get(i)[2]);
                    maxy = circles.get(i)[1] + circles.get(i)[2];

                if(miny > circles.get(i)[1] - circles.get(i)[2]);
                    miny = circles.get(i)[1] - circles.get(i)[2];

        }

        System.out.print("(" + minx + ", " + miny + ")" + ",");
        System.out.print("(" + minx + ", " + maxy + ")" + ",");
        System.out.print("(" + maxx + ", " + maxy + ")" + ",");
        System.out.print("(" + maxx + ", " + miny + ")");

    }

    public static double[] toDouble(String[] input) {
        double[] output = new double[input.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            output[i] = Double.parseDouble(input[i]);

        }

        return output;

    }

}
```

The expected output is:

```
(-3.000, -5.000), (-3.000, 3.000), (6.000, 3.000), (6.000, -5.000)
```

But instead, the output is:

```
(4.0, 1.0),(4.0, 3.0),(6.0, 3.0),(6.0, 1.0)
```

I've tried everything I can think of. For whatever reason, the final input is the maximum values found from the last circle iterated through (5,2,1) instead of the largest possible from all circles, which makes me think the conditional statements used when I'm setting the maximum and minimum values of x and y may be always evaluating to true, but I have no idea how.

If you could, clue me in on what I'm missing here or point me in the direction of what I need to learn. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is the kind of problem you can solve by using a debugger.

Comment: Although it may not be the root of the problem, parentheses in conditionals can help us understand the code quicker and confirm your intent.

Comment: Hint: Those semicolons `;` in the `if` conditions...

Comment: How about?? your expectation is wrong!!

Comment: 3rd loop :(-3.000, -5.000), (-3.000, 3.000), (6.000, 3.000), (6.000, -5.000)
 4th loop : (4.0, 1.0),(4.0, 3.0),(6.0, 3.0),(6.0, 1.0) Don't post this type of question on stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious problem:

```
if(maxx < circles.get(i)[0] + circles.get(i)[2]);
    maxx = circles.get(i)[0] + circles.get(i)[2];
```

You put a semicolon after the **if** condition.  That terminates the statement.  This translates to ...

```
if(maxx < circles.get(i)[0] + circles.get(i)[2])
    ;  // Do nothing
maxx = circles.get(i)[0] + circles.get(i)[2];
```